# Can't hide div unless there is an alert in the function

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Using this to activate a loading spinner.

Fails (div loading gif won't hide) as soon as I remove the alert:

```
$('#filters a').click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $("#filtersLoad").show(); //  Show loading gif in div
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
    alert("foo");
    if ($container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms.length) {
        $("#filtersLoad").hide(); // Hide same div when filter and layout completes.
    }
    return false;
});
```

Something rather dumb I'm sure! Also open to other approaches.

Thanks for your help!

**HTML for Loader:**

```
$("#filtersLoad, #postLoad").html('<img style=\"float:left; border:none;\" src=\"../../themes/images/ajax-loader2.gif\" width=\"54\" height=\"55\">');
});
```

**Latest Revision** This works but not pretty. Josh's code gave me a good start but I needed something that would stop the loader if the same button was clicked sequentially (see the comments below).

```
$('#filters a').click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    var lastClicked = $("#filtersLoad2").text();


if(lastClicked == selector) {

   return false;    

} 

   $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        onLayout: $("#filtersLoad").show() //  Show loading gif in div
    }, function(){
        $("#filtersLoad").hide();
        $("#filtersLoad2").text(selector);
    });

    return false;
});
```

I put the `lastClicked`value in a div since I needed it here plus may have use for it later too. And, now using Isotope's `onLayout` to show the loading div.

Comment: Show us your HTML please for the loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Isotope website](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html), you can specify a callback function as a 2nd parameter, which will fire after the animation has finished.  You'll want to hide your loading image in this callback.  Check it:

```
var currentFilter = '';

$('#filters a').click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    if (selector === currentFilter){
        return false;
    }
    currentFilter = selector;

    $("#filtersLoad").show(); //  Show loading gif in div
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    }, function(){
        $("#filtersLoad").hide();
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh. This is closer to the solution. This code works unless the same filter button (one of the `$('#filters a')` ) is clicked twice (or when that layout is already present). In that case, the div doesn't hide until another button is clicked which restarts the layout.

Comment: That actually makes sense.  I'm sure Isotope checks to see if the filter you're trying to apply is different than the one that's currently set.  If it's the same, there's no reason to re-apply the filter, and the whole process exits before the callback is fired.  So, to fix the issue, you should check to see if the filter clicked is the one that's already currently set.  If so, don't show the loading box to begin with.  Let me know if you need any help and I can put some code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Yes, that's correct. Would appreciate your approach. Guess I can store the value of last clicked somewhere and do some kind of IF. But, I'm a novice. So, if it's easy stuff for you, please do!

Comment: Yep, that works similarly to the update above. And, I am saving and using the '#filtersLoad2'. Also, you can use "onLayout" like this too:

'$container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
  onLayout: $("#filtersLoad").show()'

Answer (score 0):

> Hide same div when filter and layout completes.

Maybe I'm missing something, but how does a single if statement *wait* for the layout to complete?  As I see it, you show, you `isotop` which to my knowledge with be async, and then hide, so it won't ever show.

Comment: Yes, I am using Isotope. The function works fine when the alert("foo") is present.